# JPA cascade persistence with entity ElementCollection keys

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have two JPA entities like this:

```
@Entity
class Foo {
    @Id
    private long id;
    // ...
}

@Entity
class Bar {
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "foo_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @MapKeyClass(Foo.class)
    @Column(name = "content")
    @CollectionTable(name = "bar_foo_content",
                     joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bar_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Map<Foo, String> fooContent = Maps.newHashMap();
    // ...
}
```

As you can see, the `fooContent` field forms a many-to-many relation between `Bar` and `Foo`, so I thought it would be appropriate to use `@ManyToMany` to specify cascading for the field. However, when trying to persist a `Bar` with a couple of `Foo → String` values in the map, I get the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: <<instance of Foo>>
```

Clearly, EclipseLink does not cascade the persistence of my `Foo` instances. How should I annotate `fooContent` to get cascaded persists working?

Comment: How does your `Foo` look like? The exception looks like there is a problem between `Foo` and another entity.

Comment: @Uooo the bug still happens with the exact code above (i.e. no more fields inside Foo)

Comment: I got the same problem. Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: @drame no, I worked around the issue.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need `@ManyToMany` annotation here. Operations on `ElementCollection`s are always cascaded.

Comment: The exception is thrown even without `@ManyToMany`

Comment: this is not the case at least with mysql the fk has a cascade restricted

Answer (score 7):

It is an error to specify both `@ElementCollection` and `@ManyToMany` at the same time. The two annotations denote different concepts of OR mapping a greater-than-one cardinality relationship.

`ElementCollection` is a strict aggregation or composition relationship, where elements in the collection are strictly owned by their parent object, and any interaction with the elements, like querying etc. have to be done via the parent. The multiplicity of the parent versus the elements in the collection is always one to many. The element instances can be related to only one parent at a given point in time.

`ManyToMany` represents a relationship between more or less independent entities, that can be queried and manipulated individually and independently of the instance declaring the property annotated with `@ManyToMany`. `ManyToMany` relationships imply that the related instances can be related to any number of other instances by other declared relationships.

I'd expect that any standards-compliant JPA implementation will either show an error or exhibit "undefined" behavior for a property annotated like this.