# Cascade persist a java.util.Map<Entity, Basic> with @ElementCollection

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I try to cascade-persist the following two JPA entities (getters/setters and other fields ommited):

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name; // field only necessary so there is at least one mapping in the table

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="PROPERTY_KEY", referencedColumnName="ID")
    @Column(name="PROPERTY_VALUE")
    @CollectionTable(name="PROPERTIES")
    private Map<TestKey, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
}

@Entity
public class TestKey {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}
```

This is the code I use to persist the entity:

```
EntityManager em = ...
em.getTransaction().begin();

TestKey key = new TestKey();
key.setName("some key");
TestEntity entity = new TestEntity();
entity.getProperties().put(key, "some value");

em.persist(entity);
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

But when I do this, I get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship
>   that was not marked cascade PERSIST: TestKey

I am able to fix this by persisting the key before persisting the entity like so:

```
[...]
em.persist(key); // <<-- line added to previous example
em.persist(entity);
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

This code works as expected and persists both the `TestEntity` and the `TestKey`.

Is it somehow possible to cascade-persist the entity without explicitly persisting the key - am I perhaps doing something wrong here?

I actually thought that all `@ElementCollection` mappings are automatically cascade-persisted. I came to this conclusion from the follwing statements:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/ElementCollections

> Their is no cascade option on an ElementCollection, the target objects
>   are always persisted, merged, removed with their parent.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19517505/3270595:

> You don't need @ManyToMany annotation here. Operations on
>   ElementCollections are always cascaded.

I'm using `EclipsLink` version <del>`2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd`</del> `2.7.5.v20191016-ea124dd158`.

Comment: You have made it more then what is covered under simple collections of basic mappings by using entity references. This is functionality that was added in later JPA spec versions, and they need to be treated like any other entity references as they have their own identity and lifecycles.

Comment: Thanks Chris, so you mean, that updating to a never version of EclipseLink would likely solve the problem?

Comment: @Chris Just updated to the latest version of EclipseLink, but this didn't change anything...

Comment: No, I was referring to what the spec spelled out. Element collections were basic mappings at first, and so documented as such. Support for entities within them came later and, as they are entities, have their own lifecycle and are assumed to exist outside of the referencing entity. You must explicitly manage those referenced entities, or make them embeddable objects if you wish them to be treated as privately owned by your TestEntity instance.